# How to create a secure mysql prepared statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am new to using prepared statements in mysql with php. I need some help creating a prepared statement to retrieve columns.

I need to get information from different columns. Currently for a test file, I use the **completely unsecure** SQL statement:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM mytable where userid='{$_GET['userid']}' AND category='{$_GET['category']}'ORDER BY id DESC"
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
```

Can someone help me create a **secure** mysql statement using input from url parameters (as above) that is prepared?

BONUS: Prepared statements are suppose to increase speed as well. Will it increase overall speed if I only use a prepared statement three or four times on a page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's an example using mysqli (object-syntax - fairly easy to translate to function syntax if you desire):

```
$db = new mysqli("host","user","pw","database");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable where userid=? AND category=? ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->bind_param('ii', intval($_GET['userid']), intval($_GET['category']));
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($column1, $column2, $column3);

while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "col1=$column1, col2=$column2, col3=$column3 \n";
}

$stmt->close();
```

Also, if you want an easy way to grab associative arrays (for use with SELECT *) instead of having to specify exactly what variables to bind to, here's a handy function:

```
function stmt_bind_assoc (&$stmt, &$out) {
    $data = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
    $fields = array();
    $out = array();

    $fields[0] = $stmt;
    $count = 1;

    while($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) {
        $fields[$count] = &$out[$field->name];
        $count++;
    }
    call_user_func_array(mysqli_stmt_bind_result, $fields);
}
```

To use it, just invoke it instead of calling bind_result:

```
$stmt->store_result();

$resultrow = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $resultrow);

while($stmt->fetch())
{
    print_r($resultrow);
}
```

Comment: thanks. How do I display the results from this statement?
Generally I use mysql_fetch_row, does that work here?

Comment: Updated to add an example of how to get the results.

Comment: Also note that my example assumes that both of your paramters are integers - if they're strings, you'd need to change the arguments to bind_param accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

You can write this instead:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM mytable where userid='";
$qry.= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userid'])."' AND category='";
$qry.= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category'])."' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

But to use prepared statements you better use a generic library, like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable where userid=? and category=? 
                      order by id DESC');
$sth->execute(array($_GET['userid'],$_GET['category']));
//Consider a while and $sth->fetch() to fetch rows one by one
$allRows = $sth->fetchAll(); 
?>
```

Or, using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$category = $_GET['category'];
$userid = $_GET['userid'];

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable where 
                      userid=? and category=? order by id DESC')) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    /* Assumes userid is integer and category is string */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $userid, $category);  
    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2);
    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    /* Alternative, use a while:
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        // use $col1 and $col2 
    }
    */
    /* use $col1 and $col2 */
    echo "COL1: $col1 COL2: $col2\n";
    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

I agree with several other answers:

- PHP's `ext/mysql` has no support for parameterized SQL statements.
- Query parameters are considered more reliable in protecting against SQL injection issues.
- `mysql_real_escape_string()` can also be effective if you use it correctly, but it's more verbose to code.
- In some versions, international character sets have cases of characters that are not escaped properly, leaving subtle vulnerabilities.  Using query parameters avoids these cases.

You should also note that you still have to be cautious about SQL injection even if you use query parameters, because parameters only take the place of literal values in SQL queries.  If you build SQL queries dynamically and use PHP variables for the table name, column name, or any other part of SQL syntax, neither query parameters nor `mysql_real_escape_string()` help in this case.  For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $the_table ORDER BY $some_column";
```

Regarding performance:

- The performance benefit comes when you execute a prepared query multiple times with different parameter values.  You avoid the overhead of parsing and preparing the query.  But how often do you need to execute the same SQL query many times in the same PHP request?
- Even when you can take advantage of this performance benefit, it is usually only a slight improvement compared to many other things you could do to address performance, like using opcode caching or data caching effectively.
- There are even some cases where a prepared query *harms* performance.  For example in the following case, the optimizer can't assume it can use an index for the search, because it must assume the parameter value *might* begin with a wildcard:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE textfield LIKE ?
  ```

Comment: excellent answer. How would you suggest I handle a statement like "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE textfield LIKE ?". Should I use a prepared statement or something else?

Comment: In that specific case, you have to interpolate the pattern into the query string: "`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE textfield LIKE 'word%'`".  That way the optimizer can tell that it can use an index (of course if your pattern begins with a wildcard, an index gives no benefit anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Security with MySQL in PHP (or any other language for that matter) is a largely discussed issue. Here are a few places for you to pick up some great tips:

- http://webmaster-forums.code-head.com/showthread.php?t=939
- http://www.sitepoint.com/article/php-security-blunders/
- http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/guide-to-php-security.html
- http://www.scribd.com/doc/17638718/Module-11-PHP-MySQL-Database-Security-16

The two most major items in my opinion are:

- **SQL Injection:** Be sure to escape all of your query variables with PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string()` function (or something similar).
- **Input Validation:** Never trust the user's input. See [this](http://www.zymic.com/tutorials/php/sanitisation-and-validation-in-php/) for a tutorial on how to properly sanitize and validation your inputs.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is not great and must only be used in a string context. Never use it to try and protect a non-string field. Please, please, please use bound parameters in preference to this blacklist string-filtering band-aid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use mysqli - which seems the best solution to me - I highly recommend downloading a copy of the [codesense_mysqli](http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=189) class.

It's a neat little class that wraps up and hides most of the cruft that accumulates when using raw mysqli such that using prepared statements only takes a line or two extra over the old mysql/php interface

Comment: That class is extremely easy to use. I wonder why something like this isn't more popular.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late, but this might help someone:

```
/**
* Execute query method. Executes a user defined query
*
* @param string $query the query statement
* @param array(Indexed) $col_vars the column variables to replace parameters. The count value should equal the number of supplied parameters
*
* Note: Use parameters in the query then supply the respective replacement variables in the second method parameter. e.g. 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM foo WHERE bar = ?'
*
* @return array
*/
function read_sql($query, $col_vars=null) {
    $conn = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'user_pass', 'dbname');
    $types = $variables = array();
    if (isset($col_vars)) {
        for ($x=0; $x<count($col_vars); $x++) {
            switch (gettype($col_vars[$x])) {
                case 'integer':
                    array_push($types, 'i');
                        break;
                case 'double':
                    array_push($types, 'd');
                    break;
                default:
                    array_push($types, 's');
            }
            array_push($variables, $col_vars[$x]);
        }
        $types = implode('', $types);
        $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
        $sql -> bind_param($types, ...$variables);
        $sql -> execute();
        $results = $sql -> get_result();
        $sql -> close();
    }else {
        $results = $conn->query($query) or die('Error: '.$conn->error);
    }
    if ($results -> num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        return $result;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can then invoke the function like so:

```
read_sql('SELECT * FROM mytable where userid = ? AND category = ? ORDER BY id DESC', array($_GET['userid'], $_GET['category']));
```