# Seeking assistance with Escaping Data for MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Please don't send me a link to php.net referencing mysql_real_escape_string as the only response. I have read through the page and while I understand the general concepts, I am having some trouble based on how my INSERT statement is currently built.

Today, I am using the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('', 
                                      '$_SESSION['Member1FirstName'], 
                                      '$_SESSION['Member1LastName'], 
                                      '$_SESSION['Member1ID'], 
                                      '$_SESSION['Member2FirstName'], 
                                      '$_SESSION['Member2LastName'], 
                                      '$_SESSION['Member2ID'] ....)
```

and the list goes on for 20+ members with some other values entered. It seems most people in the examples already have all their data stored in an array.

On my site, I accept form inputs, action="" is set to self, php validation takes place and if validation passes, data is stored into SESSION variables on page 2 then redirected to the next page in the process (page 3) (approximately 8-10 pages in the whole process).

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is the safest method that doesnt involve parameterised queries, and if you're using the standard mysql driver instead of PDO or mysqli you won't have support for those.

Comment: Your query has unbalanced quotes.

Comment: @Mark I think it's only a subset of the entire query, hence the trailing ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to already know that you should be using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) but I guess you don't know *how* to use. You need to apply it for each user supplied string you insert into your SQL. The following example should clarify this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('', '" .
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Member1FirstName']) . "', '" .
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Member1LastName']) . "', '" .
    etc..
```

Or alternatively look into [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php) and bind parameters for an easier (and faster) solution.

Comment: thanks for the input. I am thinking about running mysql_real_escape_string(var) at the time I actually store the variables into SESSION, then only running INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('', '$_SESSION[Member1FirstName]'....) any issue with this? Also - what are the . "', '" . you use?

Comment: JM4: While your suggeston would work it would be easy to forget to do the escaping, and hard to notice the error if you do forget. The `.` means string concatenation and `"', '"` is just an ordinary string. With prepared statements and bind_paramaters there is very little chance to make an error and the query will be turned into a query plan faster.

Comment: is the following statement overkill? $_SESSION['F1FirstName'] = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['F1FirstName']));

Comment: @JM4: You only need htmlspecialchars if you are displaying the string as html.

Answer (score 2):

1. you're missing your closing single-quote and vars aren't replaced inside of single quotes.
2. mysql_real_escape_string is the answer, but try it with sprintf:

   $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('', '%s', '%s', '%d' )",
   mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['Member1FirstName']),
   mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['Member1LastName']),
   $_SESSION['Member1ID']); // %d forced it as a digit

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: @ Dan - 1) was just basic sample code, not prod code but understood; 2) what is benefit of using sprintf if I'm already escaping?

Comment: In this case it gives you quick access to force as number but the biggest reason is readability. You can keep your sql clean and easy to read for those ridiculously long expressions that can happen and keep your vars easily managed below. You can also make numbers have a set amount of leading zeros. All kinds of cool stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use mysql_real_escape_string?

You can also use a regexp to only allow certain characters that would be expected in a name