# PHP "SHOW TABLES" MySQLi query not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

i'm trying to execute a prepared statement with php but it doesn't work. My prepared statement is like:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE "italy_turin_mathematics"
```

and i do it like this:

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?_?_?")) {


    $stmt->bind_param('sss', "italy", "turin", "mathematics");

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($column1);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "Table: ".$column1;
    }

}
```

I'm sure it must return something, because with PHPMyAdmin it does, but with PHP it always skips the while loop, i think there is something wrong with the prepared statement query, maybe it needs to escape the underscore char?

How can i do it?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with prepared statements by why is there only three `?` and four params? Does that work?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa 'sss' means i want to bind 3 strings, and the other 3 strings are the 3 parameters i want to bind

Comment: The table's name is `italy_turin_mathematics`

Comment: What is $column1? Where is it initialized?

Comment: @Jocelyn AFAIK $column1 is initialized by `$stmt->bind_result($column1);` and it should contain the only column resulted by my query, in the answer to this question it is not initialized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php

Comment: Do you need that store_results line?

Comment: Does `echo $this->mysqli->error;` display something?

Comment: @Jocelyn where do i have to put it? if i put `echo "error: ". $this->mysqli->error;` after the while loop (after the closing loop brace) it displays nothing

Comment: I'd say after `$stmt->execute();` is the best.

Comment: @Jocelyn It prints nothing, after some tries i noticed that it is not even entering the `if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?_?_?"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot concatenate like that in mySQL, or any form of SQL I can think of.

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE ?_?_?
```

Should be:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE CONCAT(?, '_', ?, '_', ?) --this gives an error, see below
```

And I fully agree with @your-common-sense's commentary that this is a *terrible* way to design a database and you will come to regret it in more ways than just this one messed up query.

### edit:

MySQL does not seem to allow functions in a `SHOW TABLES` statement, so either you'll have to concatenate the table name to a single string in PHP, or you can use a query like:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME
FROM    
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES    
WHERE    
  table_schema = 'mydb' AND    
  table_name LIKE CONCAT(?, '_', ?, '_', ?);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It doesn't even enter the `if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE CONCAT(?, '_', ?, '_', ?)"))`

Comment: @Harlandraka then what is the error message that is generated?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(?, '_', ?, '_', ?)' at line 1`

Comment: @Harlandraka it looks like mySQL does not like any functions in a `SHOW TABLES` statement, see my edit.

Comment: Fantastic! it works, thank you! (and yes, i will change my database structure, i know it is not normalized, i just wanted to know how to do it)

Answer (score 1):

Your database architecture is utterly **wrong**.

There should be **only one table** contains all the data, for all the places and sciences.
And you have to query it usual way, without employing `SHOW TABLES` at all.

So, it have to be something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE country=? AND city=? and science=?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array("italy", "turin", "mathematics"));
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

the above code is in PDO, as you have to use it instead of mysqli.

Splitting tables is a very bad idea, violating the very fundamental rules of relational databases. As you can see, it makes you to run such a strange query and will make your further code even worse.

Comment: Why not posting a comment? my question is about how to make my query work, and this is not an answer to it, i know it is wrong to name different tables but i need to do it and i need to know why my query doesn't work.

Comment: Why PDO? Do you have a good reason to say so?
I really think you don't.

Also, your architecture too, is awful. (and it breaks all the normal forms)

Comment: Once you've used both PDO and MySQLi you'll probably reach the same conclusion. If you have the option, choose PDO and avoid accruing technical debt. Pros and cons [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: @Mathieu +1. Although first one is obvious, your second objection is absolutely correct.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: MySQLi is good for high-traffic environments. +5% of performance on DB Queries (which are by far the slowest operations on web applications) is not something to be skipped on.

I used PDO for a while for it's ease of use, and fell back to MySQLi  because it's less buggy, faster, and once you have a nice wrapper around it, it's just awesome.

Comment: @Mathieu Unfortunately, there is no real life difference. These 5% are fictional, gotten on artificial tests. While on a live site you'd never notice it. One have to optimize the query itself, not API running it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?")) {

    $country = "italy";
    $city = "turin";
    $course = "mathematics";

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $country . "_" . $city . "_" . $course);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($column1);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "Table: ".$column1;
    }

}
```

As far as I know the code you had would result in a query looking as follows:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'italy'_'turin'_'mathematics'
```

Comment: AFAIK in prepared statements you must not use single or double quotes around a `?` parameter...