# PHP query structure

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to learn object oriented **mysqli** and I have a (pretty basic I'm sure) question. I am following the guide [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

When it comes to writing queries, what's the difference (if any) between the following queries;

**First**

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `live` = 1 
SQL;
```

**Second**

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE live = 1");
```

I would like to start as I mean to go on so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking the difference in PHP or SQL?

Comment: You should start off with PDO/mysqlnd.... mysqli is all but deprecated.

Comment: @winmutt incorrect `mysqli` is not deprecated, `mysql_` is.

Comment: @winmutt Uhm, mysqli is not deprecated. [ext/mysql is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: He did say all *but* deprecated

Comment: PDO's named placeholders make it a lot more friendly to use and variable binding is way easier because of it.

Comment: @PatrickMurphy That's like saying you should use Python because PHP is all but deprecated. It's misleading at best and dishonest at worst. mysqli is here to stay.

Comment: I wasn't agreeing with him just clarifying he didn't claim it was deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is heredoc syntax: [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

They both serve the same purpose. Using heredoc makes it easier to mix static text with variables without having to worry about string concatenation or using `{$variable}` to have variables inside strings.

Using heredoc also allows multilining your queries for easier reading in a cleaner way.

Disclaimer: I don't use heredoc extensively, but for lengthy queries it makes it easier to break down in lines and read them :)

Comment: Thanks @BlunT I've actually never heard of this but I'm reading about it now. I'm not sure which one I will decide to go with but at least my question is answered!

Comment: You can use multiple lines with double quotes too.

Comment: @DaveChen you're right, it just seems cleaner with heredoc :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate concatenation instead.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ' . (int)$somevar . ' LIMIT 1';
```

Or you can skip the concatenation in SQL and use a [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php) instead.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 1';
```

Heredoc does allow inlining but it's also MUCH stricter on rules and sometimes creates strange problems in coding, **especially when you want to indent code** (the closing string has to be on a line by itself with no indenting). Consider that it is considered a best practice that you indent code when you have code inside a block statement

```
// Syntax error
if($something) {
    $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `live` = 1 
    SQL;
}
```

I know of no major open source PHP that makes extensive use of heredoc. Most write standard strings and either escape the data or use prepared statements

Comment: I mentined concatenation as means to building dynamic queries, not for concatenating parameters. But I totally hate that . notation . I like this better: `$var = "SELECT * FROM {$mytable}";`