# Can't get data from database using mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have got this code

```
$dafirstname = "SELECT fullname FROM websiteusers WHERE userName='$usernamer'";
$differentvariables = mysqli_query($link, $dafirstname);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($differentvariables, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["pass"], $row["userID"]);

if(!mysqli_query($link,$dafirstname)){
  echo mysqli_error($link);     
}
```

But it does not print any thing or it is not giving any errors

Comment: have you enabled php errors?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: also, as a side note (not to fix your problem), consider prepared statements to avoid sql injection:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php

Comment: @devlincarnate Okay thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query. You were asking fullname only. change it to see the result.

```
$dafirstname="SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE userName='$usernamer'";
$differentvariables=mysqli_query($link,$dafirstname);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($differentvariables,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["pass"], $row["userID"]);
if(!mysqli_query($link,$dafirstname)){
  echo mysqli_error($link);     
}
```

Comment: He should use `SELECT pass, userID` -- no need to select `*` if he doesn't use anything else.

Comment: Oh no its working thanks.I will accept you answer in 50 seconds

Comment: I Am Glad. :) @MuradMurader