# Mysql insert into string value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert values from a string like $email $password $username

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cyrexhosting`.`users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) 
             VALUES ('123', '123', '123'");
```

but i don't know how

Comment: Is that all you have?

Comment: See this: http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: You want to use something called "prepared statements" for this and the MySQLi driver (vs the mysql one you are using).

Comment: I honestly don't know which question to close this with, amongst 15,000

Comment: Does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the *deprecated* mysql function:

```
$user = "121";
$pass = "dummy1";
$email = "dummy@dummy.com";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username, password, email) VALUES('$user', '$pass', '$email')");
```

On the other hand, using `mysqli`:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) 
VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$email')");
```

> Note: where `$con` is the mysqli connection made variable.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to use variable values instead of '123'

Comment: @devlincarnate _if_ that is the case, edited.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Please do not demonstrate bad technique in answers. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).