# Unable to insert more than one row in MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Here is my PHP code:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$connection = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$username   = $connection->real_escape_string($username);
$html       = $connection->real_escape_string($html);
$connection->query("INSERT INTO savedarticles (username, article) VALUES ('$username', '$html')");
```

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'savedarticle.php',
  data: {
    html: innerHTML,
    username: '<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>'    
  }
});
```

`$html` has a unique value every time. Let's say I have two values:

1. username = alpha , html = bla, bla class="bla"
2. username = alpha , html = more bla class="bla"

By class I want to signify there are double quotes in the HTML but I am escaping them. If I click on any one of these two the value are stored in database but no subsequent values are stored. If I click on 1 first it will be saved and later clicking on 2 won't have any effect. If I click on 2 first it will be saved and later clicking on 1 won't have any effect.
In case it matters I have another table with same column name `username`. Also my table `savedarticles` has an `Id` column with `int` values, `username` column with type `varchar(255)` and `article` column with type `text`.

Comment: Please do not build queries by interpolating strings (`'$username'`), this is incredibly unsafe and brittle. Prepared statements were made to address this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1290995/252218

Comment: Does `$html` contains html elements?

Comment: try to print log on ajax to see if it's still working after first trigger.

Comment: What triggers `$.ajax({`? Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code. Please have a look and try .

```
<?php
$html = $_POST['html'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$connection = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$username   = $connection->real_escape_string($username);
$html       = $connection->real_escape_string($html);
$connection->query("INSERT INTO savedarticles (username, article) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$html."')");

?>
```