# php were name=1 and id=equal number but Not specified

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT title, nodeid FROM node 
 where contenttypeid='30' and starter=equal nubber(but Not a fixed number) 
 order by nodeid desc limit 10";
```

Can someone help me? What is the right way to use "and starter=equal nubber(but Not a fixed number)"

Comment: Use preparedStatement and then bind the values.

Comment: can you write for me an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a secure mysql prepared statement in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(int)` instead of `(float)` if you need only integer numbers.

```
$number = 12.112; //some number
$sql = "
    SELECT title, nodeid 
    FROM node 
    WHERE contenttypeid= 30 and starter = " . (float) $number . "
    ORDER BY nodeid desc 
    LIMIT 10
";
```