# Redirecting user after login with header("Location") is not working

Tags: php, redirect

I have a problem about redirecting the user. I want to land user on my specified page.

I tried

```
header("Location: http://www.website.com");
```

but it is not working.

When I log in as testing user with correct password and email, `login.php` page remains same. I want the user to land on `index.php` instead.

My second problem is that if the user is not logged in and tries to enter index.php, how do I redirect the user to login page (login.php)

here is my code for login (login.php)
Note:(all php codes are above the html lines)

```
<?php
session_start();
$message = "";
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user name", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("db_name", $conn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='" . $_POST["user_name"] . "' and password = '" . $_POST["password"] . "'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (is_array($row)) {
        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[user_id];
        $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[user_name];
    } else {
        $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

where i want to redirect user and if not logged in want to land user on login.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please only post relevant parts of your code, so that it would be easier for others to diagnose the problems, thanks :)

Comment: try java-script for that

Comment: okay what about if user is not logged in :)

Comment: You have some problems here: Sql injection, passwords stored as plain text and you are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions that have been removed from php 7.

Comment: aham yes you are right but my hosting package has lower php level

Comment: @waleedkhan as long as it's PHP5 then you should be using `MySQLi_` as a minimum. Jump before you're pushed `:-)`

Comment: i have jumped already :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some problems here: Sql injection, passwords stored as plain text and you are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions that have been removed from php 7.

Apart from that, you have your logic the wrong way around:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

should be:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
//  ^ redirect to login if the variable is NOT set
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

See these links for more information about sql injection / prepared statements and password hashing:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [How can I store my users' passwords safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely)

Comment: // comment that `^ redirect..` to save a nub :D

Comment: @Zanderwar Hmmmmmm, all this should really be thrown away and be rewritten from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are empty lines above the starting `<?php` tag in your login.php.

Also you have mysql injection in your query. If one inputs `' or 'a'='a` as the password the query would be

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='' and password = '' or 'a'='a'"
```

so it would ignore any username oder password protection. You need to escape the variables passed to the query. The easiest way would be

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='" . addslashes($_POST["user_name"]) . "' and password = '". addslashes($_POST["password"]) ."'"
```

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

There are some other problems with your code:

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array of form `array(0 => 'field value 1', 1 => 'field value 2')` and so on. What you need is `mysql_fetch_assoc` for an associative array (field names as array keys).

`$row[user_id]` the user_id here is a constant but if it is not set it would return a string `user_id`, but you should avoid that kind of use and do it the right way `$row['user_id']`

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (is_array($row)) {
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row['user_name'];
} else {
    $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
```

Since you redirect is not triggered the only possibility is that no user is found or you have a mysql error. You can check that with `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: there is no empty lines above the srating <?php tag

Comment: I have added some other info. Check if there are mysql errors after your query

Answer (score 0):

**1**

As rightly pointed out by [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39291696/3536236), you need to STOP using `MySQL_` because it is deprecated. It doesn't matter what version of PHP your hosting provider has, you should be making strong efforts to upgrade and update to `MySQLi_` *at least* if not (with more time and learning) you can use [MySQLi Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php) or [PDO Prepared Statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

**2**

If you can't understand the behaviour that is being output by your PHP script -you're expecting it to work and it doesn't- then the solution is almost always in the PHP Error logs. Please Read up on [how to output PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). This will give you concise and informative identification if your issues.

**3** *(This is the important one and the impetus for my answer)*

While Jeroens answer does appear to be correct, there is a very important caveat that has been missed out, and that is once you've written you redirection header to take the user to the intended page, you ***MUST*** follow this with a `die` or `exit` command, otherwise the script will keep running, but will only take the user to the "*last encountered header location".

An example:

```
if($login === false){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
header("Location: welcome.php");
```

Each and every time this is run, the user will be taken to `welcome.php` because even if they're not logged in, the script will execute both headers but will only follow the most recent, the last one.

So, always add `exit` statements *immediately* after headers to ensure that they redirect as intended.

```
if($login === false){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
header("Location: welcome.php");
exit;
```

**4**

Please try and avoid bad habits before they become habits, again, as Jeroen mentions, you should ***not store passwords as plain text*** and at the very least research [various hashing methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581919/3536236).

Also quote your array keys, so that `$row[user_id];` becomes `$row['user_id'];`

***NEVER*** trust user supplied data such as `$_POST` or `$_GET` or `$_COOKIE` data, it can be easily tampered with and abused by the user or any [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Try and get into a habit for using [Cross Site Request Forgery prevention methods](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) as well as fully escaping and cleaning all user supplied data.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement below should follow the function session_start();

```
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: buddy you did good. but please explain your code a little bit