# How to insert php codes into database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert-into

I'm testing my mysql codes vulnerability.
This is the php injection:

```
$myvar = "varname";
$x = $_GET['arg'];
eval("\$myvar = \$x;");
```

Or any other php code, like blow:

```
<?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

My purpose is to insert them into DB but don't execute them.
Actualy these codes are gonna inserted into DB from an html input form by a user and I wan to display them for the user.(sth like messaging)
**Problem**:
The problem is that when I try to insert them into DB it fails, my insert query is this:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO table (usr,id,message,date) VALUES ($usr,'$id','$message','$date')");
```

The codes are in `$message`.
I also should add this validation function:

```
function validate($data)
{
    stripslashes($data);
    htmlspecialchars($data);
    htmlentities($data);
    strip_tags($data);
    addslashes($data);
    return($data);
}
```

Before inserting `$message` into DB I have validated it by this function `validate($message)`  but even this can't fix the problem.

---

I have searched but there's no results for this question in google!
Any one knows how to insert codes into mysql database?

Comment: simply use prepared-statemants and not clearing the insert data by yourself. By the way: How about `base64_encode` before saving into database. Then you dont have problems with single-quotes and backslashes that can be a part of php.

Comment: And just a note on your `validate()` function: You return the data unchanged. Normaly in php you will do this `$data = stripslashes($data);` `$data = htmlspecialchars($data);` depends on the used function. Readmore on php.net for each function.

Comment: just read about prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape your input data with a `real_escape_string` function: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Now you can safely create a legal SQL string that you can use in an SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew this function but I haven't used it for a long time and I completely forgot it!

Comment: Also I should add this to your answer to complete it: Use `htmlspecialchars()` to show php codes in html page.

Comment: And an even better idea is to use prepared statements, as @Alex mentioned too. My solution is strictly for your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

To insert code php in database, following this options :
1. To insert data, use htmlspecialchars. example :

```
$string = '<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>';
htmlspecialchars($string);
```

2. Before read/get data, use htmlspecialchars_decode. Example : `htmlspecialchars_decode($string);`

   Hope this maybe can help you :-)