# Creating a prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I wanted to write a `PHP` script in which i had to execute `INSERT` query in `MySQL` database using prepared statement.

As i am a beginner in `PHP`, i had no idea how to do it. so I looked it up on `Stackoverflow` and found this [How to create a secure mysql prepared statement in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php)
.

So i started doing it in same way as done in the accepted answer **BUT** in the answer, there are some methods used, like

1. `prepare` to prepare the `SELECT` query
2. `bind_param` to bind parameters to query
3. `close` to close to `$stmt`

which are not suggested to me by `Visual Studio Code` when i try to use them. Also when i use these methods and hover the pointer over them, no documentation is shown by the `Visual Studio Code` which made me think whether these methods are available anymore or not.

Instead of `prepare` method, `Visual Studio Code` suggests `odbc_prepare`, instead of `bind_param`, it suggests `mysqli_bind_param` and instead of `close`, it suggests `odbc_close`.

I am using `PHP 7.2`

**Question:** Are methods like `prepare`, `close`, `bind_param` not available in `PHP 7` and can i use the ones suggested to me by `Visual Studio Code` in place of these methods ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: *"Question: Are methods like prepare, close, bind_param not available in PHP 7 and can i use the ones suggested to me by Visual Studio Code in place of these methods ?"* - Why wouldn't they be available in php 7? Did you not go through the manual(s) at all before posting?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i did go through the documentation. According to _Gant's_ answer, `prepare` or `bind_param` can only be used with `mysqli` prefix but have a look at this [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) where they have used `prepare` and `bind_param` methods with `mysqli` object. I am doing the same thing but `Visual Studio Code` is not suggesting these methods at all.

Comment: because VSC is not focused on php ! you are not gonna see suggests  about everything just few functions and methods, there's some php IDEs out there that suggest way more. just google "PHP IDE" ( i personally use atom, it doesn't suggest 99% of php functions and no methods suggestions at all ! but still like it, clean and faster then VSC )

Answer (score 1):

Those function are not a standalone functions. They are methods of PDO objects. To learn more about PDO check this tutorial: [PDO Tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

```
$pdo = new PDO();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND status=:status');
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email, 'status' => $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use these functions without an `mysqli` object in the procedural style with the `mysqli_` prefix.

The object-orinted style is usually preferred however.

[PHP.net has a comparison of the two approches](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

Comment: Have a look at [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) where they have used these methods with `mysqli` object. When i use the object approach, these methods are not suggested, they are only suggested when using procedural approach.