# How do I store the name and the path of the file in my database?

Tags: php, mysqli, file-upload

Uploading the  file is okay, but storing the path and the name of the file into my database is not.

**This is my form html.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
```

```
<form action="../model/uploadcredentials.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" placeholder="Upload your credentials">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**And here is my action file**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]))
{
    $target_dir = "../assets/credentials/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;

        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
        {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

            $file = stripcslashes($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            $file = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$file);
            $query = $con->query("INSERT INTO `portfolio`(p.desc) VALUES('$file')");
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I`am trying to get the filename and the path to store it in my database

Comment: What problem do you exactly encounter? I don't see where `$con` is coming from?

Comment: $con is for the connection.

Comment: It's always worth checking for and reporting errors, it might be that in your INSERT, `(p.desc)` is trying to find a table called `p` (usually an alias) which isn't defined.  Try `(desc)`.

Comment: You should also look into prepared statements as this has loads of benefits.

Comment: the problem is im having trouble storing the filename and the path into my database.

Comment: @HarlyDakay I know `$con` is for the connection, and we know what you try to achieve. We need details. Which errors do you get? What goes wrong? What have you tried to solve this problem? Why can't you work it out? Etc. Remember that we cannot run your code. It's incomplete, and we don't know your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

It's always worth checking for and reporting errors.

In your INSERT, `(p.desc)` is trying to find a table called `p` (usually an alias) which isn't defined. Try...

```
$query = $con->query("INSERT INTO portfolio(desc) VALUES('$file')");
```

(Without the `p.`).

BUT I still recommend using prepared statements, have a read of [How to create a secure mysql prepared statement in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php)